# Sum of values of a listbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, listbox

I have a `TextBox` in WPF and a `ListBox`. `ListBox` (listAmount) is containing some values and I want the sum of that values in that `TextBox` (txtTotalAmount).

I am using currently this code:

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < listAmount.Items.Count; i++)
{
    sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(listAmount.Items[i]);
}

txtTotalAmount.Text = sum.ToString();
```

And I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'

I will be greatfull to you.

Answer (score 6):

The error message explains that `listAmount.Items[i]` returns instances of type [`ListBoxItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx). That class is derived from [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx), which is why its [`Content` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) should contain the actual value you are looking for.

Therefore, try:

```
sum += Convert.ToInt32(((ListBoxItem)listAmount.Items[i]).Content);
```

The typecast is necessary because the [indexer of `ItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.item.aspx) is typed to `object`.

---

That said, have you tried using a collection (e.g. an [`ObservableCollection<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)) to store your values and set that collection as the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) of your listbox? You could then directly grab and sum up the integer values from your collection without the necessity to convert anything.

Add this declaration to your window to store a list of integer values:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<int> values = new ObservableCollection<int>();
```

Then, after your call to `InitializeComponents`, assign the `ItemsSource` property:

```
listAmount.ItemsSource = values;
```

Add and remove your values to and from the `values` list whenever you like then; the contents of the list will always be reflected by the listbox.

For retrieving the sum of those values, you can then simply use the following:

```
int sum = values.Sum();
```

Note that the [`System.Linq` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) needs to be included with a `using` directive for this to work, or the [`Sum` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx) will not be found.)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend another approach that blends better to WPF / XAML.

Use a binding on your Textbox.Text, and create a property in your object that you bind to. Perform the math in the getter of the property. I would restrain from manually assigning the Textbox.Text value every time it changes. Binding is one of WPFs biggest advantages VS Winforms.

This of course requires that your object implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

EDIT: IF you absolutely have to do it without bindings that i'd recommend summing up using a LINQ query. Simple and elegant (for this example my ListBox has an ItemSource that is an array if integers. You would of course have to adapt the Cast<> to whatever you are using).

```
  var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
  var listBox = new ListBox {ItemsSource = numbers};

  var sum = listBox.Items.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that they will always be integers you can use Linq

```
 listAmmount.Items.Cast<string>().Sum(x => int.Parse(x)).ToString();
```

**Edit**

Tested in wpf

```
textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Content)).ToString();
```

Comment: The `Cast<>` would have to be `ListBoxItem`  something like `int sum = listbox1.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Content.ToString()));`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 ok sorry about that. it's pretty late over here so ... just deleted my post

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - Thanks, I had tested in winforms first assuming wpf was similar, attached a version I quickly tested successfully

Answer (score -2):

Use :

```
listAmount.Items[i].ToString()
```

Answer (score -3):

There Is probably a much cleaner way of doing it, but this

```
 var items = listAmount.Items;
        int SUM;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            int itemvalue = Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString());

            SUM += itemvalue;
        }
```